# Compiler warning about "Semantic Issue" -- how to fix?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, datepicker, warnings

I receive this warning when building my app:

> warning: Semantic Issue: Local declaration of 'datePicker' hides instance variable

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: @ DownVoter : Can you post a comment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a method with parameter named `datePicker`. This method is located in a class which has a field with the same name.

You need to change a name of one of these variables to get rid of this warning.

Answer (score 1):

rename your ivars like this:

```
@interface SomeClass{
  NSString * _datePicker;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * datePicker;
@end

@implementation SomeClass

@synthesize datePicker =_datePicker;

...
```